# Activity has leaked window android that was originally

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I have little problem with my TextView in activity. I create activity with alphabet Sidebar and overlayView for drawing alphabet character

I would like destroy/close whatever, my TextView.

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.package.activity.ActSklep has leaked window android.widget.TextView@406afc78 that was originally added here

com.package.activity.ActSklep has leaked window android.widget.TextView@4063f550 that was originally added here
```

My code: http://pastebin.com/WqhULBfA

Edit:
Class sidebar
http://pastebin.com/prRZ9nsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding your textView to window in `onCreate` try removing it in `onDestroy`:

```
((WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(overlayTextView);
```

Comment: I dont know how i doing to this

Comment: Yes, i found the same solution